# Android Studio 3.4.2 : Could not find support-core-ui Any Solutions Not Work

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-build

I Wrote Android Project 20 days Ago
but Today I Decide Opening Project For Maintenance 
I See This Error : Please See This Picture :
Picture 1 : Error Log :
[image]

Android Support Library Installed Latest Version On My Machine :
Picture 2 : Android Support Installed :
[image]

I Tested This Url With My Browser : Google Remove This File 
Picture 3 : Really Google Removed This File !
[image]

What Do For Solve This Problem :
1-Invalidate Cache /Restart 
2-Change repositories priority :

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}
3-set build tools to Latest version :

```
    buildToolsVersion = '29.0.2'
```

I do Not Know How Solve This Problem
thx

Comment: I Use This dependencies :   `dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good News :) I Solved This Problem By :
First I Updated Dependencies Support To Version 28:

```
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Second : After This Change Get Error :
**Error:Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable**

Finally Use This Priority repositories :

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()


    }
}
```